# angular material tree accessing node and child elements

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement an angular material tree i.e. having node and child element. I want to set and get the id of the element in HTML code and access that particular node element in the ts file. How to implement it?

Comment: Hi Harshada. I see you're new. Please could you add some code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: Following example I m trying to implement it. 
 https://stackblitz.com/angular/lrvjomddovo?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts